# Check if a property was set - using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, properties, mocking, moq

I am new to Moq and testing in general so here is my noobish Q.
How do I test if the **Status** property on **Request** has been set using Moq?

```
public class DudeManager
{
        private readonly IDRepository _repo;

        public DManager(IDRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public void Create(Request r)
        {
            r.Status = Status.Submitted;
            _repo.AddRequest(r);
        }
}
```

Is there a better approach than the following? Maybe using VerifySet?

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void AddingNewRequestSetsStatusToSubmitted()
        {
            //Arrange
            var mock = new Mock<IDRepository>();
            var mockRequest = new Mock<Request>();
            var dManager = new DManager(mock.Object);

            //Act
            dManager.Create(mockRequest.Object);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(Status.Submitted, mockRequest.Object.Status);
        }
```

**EDIT:** This is the approach I ended up using after all the helpful suggestions:

```
//Arrange
var request = new Request();
var mock = new Mock<IDRepository>();
var dManager = new DManager(mock.Object);
mock.Setup(x => x.AddRequest(It.IsAny<Request>()));

//Act
dManager.QueueNewRequest(request);

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(RequestStatus.Submitted, request.Status);
```

This approach seems right to me. Does anyone think otherwise?

Comment: I believe VerifySet is the best fit.

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to use it? I tried using VerifySet but it blows up on me.

Comment: I'm not convinced VerifySet does anything at all, I've never been able to fail a test with it, always passes. I go through the debugger and see my mock is callbase true, property in question is null, no invocations. VerifySet with a vale "Hello world" and the thing goes... pass. I would go with the unit testing framework and assert this equal that.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think VerifySet is the right approach. It would look something like this:

```
//Arrange
var mock = new Mock<IDRepository>();
var mockRequest = new Mock<Request>();
// TODO: set some expectations here

var dManager = new DManager(mock.Object);

//Act
dManager.Create(mockRequest.Object);

//Assert
mockRequest.VerifySet(x => x.Status = Status.Submitted);
```

I believe in your case, it blows up because you haven't set up your Request mock to handle the set operation on Status.

One easy way to do that is using `SetupAllProperties`, like so:

```
//Arrange
var mock = new Mock<IDRepository>();
var mockRequest = new Mock<Request>();
mockRequest.SetupAllProperties();
```

Comment: It still fails with the following error: Test Outcome: Failed
threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member:

Comment: Of course, Request isn't an interface in your case. You'd need to mark the Status property as virtual for this to work. And, as @AD.net mentioned below, unless Request has some complex behavior, there's no need to mock it.

Comment: The other answer by Ufuk Hacıoğulları worked too but I modified this version without the mocked Request object. I liked the idea of not mocking the Request object and then using the Assert class to check if it is equal - not sure if this is the right way but it feels right to me (edited the post to show my modified/working version. Please comment if it is a bad practice.

Comment: Not at all, I would only mock objects that have complex interactions that interfere with your ability to test. It's always preferable to use the real thing.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should use strict behavior by default, then you can make the verification with a single call. It also makes you write your test more explicitly.

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddingNewRequestSetsStatusToSubmitted()
{
    //Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IDRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var mockRequest = new Mock<Request>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var dManager = new DManager(mock.Object);

    mockRequest.SetupSet(item => item.Status = It.IsAny<StatusType>())
               .Verifiable();

    //Act
    dManager.Create(mockRequest.Object);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(mockRequest.Object.Status, Status.Submitted);
    mock.VerifyAll();
    mockRequest.VerifyAll();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
mock.Verify(m=>m.AddRequest(It.Is<Request>(r=>r.Status == expectedStatus)));
```

You can verify that the `AddRequest` method gets called with parameter (`Request`) which has the correct `Status`. Also, mocking the `Request` object is not really necessary here.